# Isn't Reactjs supposed to reload automatically when authentication is checked?

Tags: reactjs

first im new to Reactjs and I working on a project where user has to logging to continue to the site, but when the user is logged in I get a white screen and then I have to reload for it to continue.

I get this error in the console

Warning: React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

Please help.

Profile.js

```
import React from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { Redirect } from "react-router-dom";
import Hoc from "../hoc/hoc";

class Profile extends React.Component {
    render() {
        if (this.props.token === null) {
          return <Redirect to="/" />;
        }
        return (
          <div className="contact-profile">
            {this.props.username !== null ? (
              <Hoc>
                <img src="http://emilcarlsson.se/assets/harveyspecter.png" alt="" />
                <p>{this.props.username}</p>
                <div className="social-media">
                  <i className="fa fa-facebook" aria-hidden="true" />
                  <i className="fa fa-twitter" aria-hidden="true" />
                  <i className="fa fa-instagram" aria-hidden="true" />
                </div>
              </Hoc>
            ) : null}
          </div>
        );
      }
    }

const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
        username: state.auth.username,
        token: state.auth.token
      };
    };
    
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Profile);
```

Index.js

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { createStore, compose, applyMiddleware, combineReducers } from "redux";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import thunk from "redux-thunk";
import "antd/dist/antd.css";
import authReducer from "./store/reducers/auth";
import navReducer from "./store/reducers/nav";
import messageReducer from "./store/reducers/message";
import App from "./App";

const composeEnhancers = window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ || compose;

function configureStore() {
    const rootReducer = combineReducers({
        auth: authReducer,
        nav: navReducer,
        message: messageReducer
      });
    
      const store = createStore(
        rootReducer,
        composeEnhancers(applyMiddleware(thunk))
      );
    
        if (module.hot) {
          module.hot.accept("./store/reducers", () => {
            const nextRootReducer = require("./store/reducers/auth");
            store.replaceReducer(nextRootReducer);
          });
        }
    
      return store;
    }
    
    const store = configureStore();
    
    const app = (
        <Provider store={store}>
            <App />
        </Provider>
    )


ReactDOM.render(app, document.getElementById("app"));
```

Its just a one page website, so they get redirected to the same page, the login is just somewhere on top. Thank you for your help

Comment: Please, can you provide more code? Just the logic... Otherwise is impossible to help you...

Comment: OKay, which part of the code please? Index.js, App.js, Route.js?

Comment: According to what the error said, your problem could be related to the page you navigate after user is logged in. Can you show me this page and Login page?

Comment: Okay. I will edit the Main question right away you will find it there please

Comment: In profile component, it returns false condition. That's why you see white screen. Please check the auth check action creator and make sure it is implemented correctly

Comment: Okay Yes. I have gotten it. Thanks alot